# ui-router use "Resolve" in state custom property

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making a breadcrumb component based on ui-router states. So this is what I achieve.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
   // custom property
   breadcrumb: 'Home',
   // other properties
   // ... 
});

$stateProvider.state('home.profile', {
   breadcrumb: 'Profile',
   // ...
});
```

So this works fine and when I enter the 'home.profile' state, I get "Home / Profile" breadcrumb. But how can I display dynamic data? Like user name. I'd like to something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('home.profile', {
   resolve: {
      currentUser: ($http) => {
         return $http.get('current-user');
      }
   },

   // I would like to "inject" the resolved currentUser
   breadcrumb: (currentUser) => {
      return currentUser.username;
   }
});
```

I know that using components there is a $resolve service where you can do this:

```
<my-component user="$resolve.currentUser.username"></my-component>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about your use case where you want to resolve your `customData`, but in you can inject your resolved data into your controller.

```
$stateProvider.state('home.profile', {
   resolve: {
      currentUser: ($http) => {
         return $http.get('current-user');
      }
   },
});
```

and in your controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', 'currentUser', function($scope, currentUser) {

   // you can be sure the data will be here because resolve are resolved before controller is instantiated
    $scope.UserName = currentUser.username; 
  }]);
```

Then in your view it will be pretty much intuitive:

```
<my-component user="UserName"></my-component> //depends how your directive is binded
```

Comment: I'd like the same behaviour of controllers but in my custom "breadcrumb" object property.